# Windows 8.1 Powershell Set-DisplayResolution

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, server-core

I found a technet article to set the display resolution using powershell and Windows Server Core Cmdlets.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603036.aspx

However when I try to run the cmd `PS C:\> Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1200` I get an error saying the Set-DisplayResoluton is a unknown cmd.  I know this cmd is for administering server core functionlaity but can it be used in Windows 8.1.  And if so, how do I load the cmdlet in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this on Windows 8.1? It looks like the command might only be available on Windows Server 2012 R2 Server Core. I understand that the article says otherwise, but I just checked on my Windows 8.1 computers, and do not have the command in the session.

```
Get-Command -Name *resolu*;
```